# counting frequency in list

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a list of lists:

```
countall = [[5, 0], [4, 1], [4, 1], [3, 2], [4, 1], [3, 2], [3, 2], [2, 3], [4, 1], [3, 2], [3, 2], [2, 3], [3, 2], [2, 3], [2, 3], [1, 4], [4, 1], [3, 2], [3, 2], [2, 3], [3, 2], [2, 3], [2, 3], [1, 4], [3, 2], [2, 3], [2, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [1, 4], [1, 4], [0, 5]]
```

I would like to find the frequency of sub-lists in the above list.

I have tried to use itertools:

```
freq = [len(list(group)) for x in countall for key, group in groupby(x)]
```

However, I am getting the wrong results:

```
[1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1]
```

What is wrong with my list comprehension?

Comment: The code you've shown isn't valid syntax, there's a parenthesis missing. If you want frequencies, look into `collections.Counter`.

Comment: `groupby` looks for _consecutive repetitions_, so you should _sort the list_ before `groupby`-ing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as pointed by ForceBru first sort your list then use groupby:

```
from itertools import groupby
countall = [[5, 0], [4, 1], [4, 1], [3, 2], [4, 1], [3, 2], [3, 2], [2, 3], [4, 1], [3, 2], [3, 2], [2, 3], [3, 2], [2, 3], [2, 3], [1, 4], [4, 1], [3, 2], [3, 2], [2, 3], [3, 2], [2, 3], [2, 3], [1, 4], [3, 2], [2, 3], [2, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [1, 4], [1, 4], [0, 5]]

freq = [(key, len(list(x))) for key, x in groupby(sorted(countall))]
print(freq)
```

output:

```
[([0, 5], 1), ([1, 4], 5), ([2, 3], 10), ([3, 2], 10), ([4, 1], 5), ([5, 0], 1)]
```

your code has bugs:

```
freq = [len(list(group)) for x in countall for key, group in groupby(x)]
                       ^paranthesis missing
```

Then you are grouping each individual list in `countall` which is not needed.

```
for x in countall for key, group in groupby(x)
```

yo can directly `groupby` on sorted(countall)

Also, as answered by @Bemmu you can use collections.Counter. But that does not support `list` so first you will have to convert your data to tupple or string then use `Counter`

Answer (score 4):

Groupby seems to deal with sequences that come after each other. To use it you would need to sort the list first. Another option is to use the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class:

```
from collections import Counter
countall = [[5, 0], [4, 1], [4, 1], [3, 2], [4, 1], [3, 2], [3, 2], [2, 3], [4, 1], [3, 2], [3, 2], [2, 3], [3, 2], [2, 3], [2, 3], [1, 4], [4, 1], [3, 2], [3, 2], [2, 3], [3, 2], [2, 3], [2, 3], [1, 4], [3, 2], [2, 3], [2, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [1, 4], [1, 4], [0, 5]]
Counter([tuple(x) for x in countall])
```

Output:

```
Counter({(3, 2): 10, (2, 3): 10, (1, 4): 5, (4, 1): 5, (5, 0): 1, (0, 5): 1})
```

Comment: ```collections.Counter```

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments you will need to sort if you are using groupby.

**Code:**

```
import itertools as it
freq = {tuple(key): len(list(group)) for key, group in it.groupby(sorted(countall))}
```

**Test Code:**

```
countall = [[5, 0], [4, 1], [4, 1], [3, 2], [4, 1], [3, 2], [3, 2], [2, 3],
           [4, 1], [3, 2], [3, 2], [2, 3], [3, 2], [2, 3], [2, 3], [1, 4],
           [4, 1], [3, 2], [3, 2], [2, 3], [3, 2], [2, 3], [2, 3], [1, 4],
           [3, 2], [2, 3], [2, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [1, 4], [1, 4], [0, 5]]

print(freq)
```

**Results:**

```
{(3, 2): 10, (1, 4): 5, (2, 3): 10, (5, 0): 1, (0, 5): 1, (4, 1): 5}
```